# Is html needed when making an Android app?

Tags: android

Is html needed when making an Android app? For example, the game I play there are buildings which you can construct and upgrade.Now is this done by html?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This post does not match the site requirements for asking a question. Please learn [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, short answer - no.

Most android apps are developed using Java as the programming language, with a mark-up language which could be comparable to HTML (but is **not** HTML) to build the basic UI structure of most screens.

Certain aspects of HTML are still used in Android apps, for example, when we'd like to construct a label with styling (such as a bold word in the middle of a sentence, etc). Also, Android is capable of presenting a `WebView` which can display HTML and run JavaScript. There's also a way to leverage HTML to make apps which can run on both Android and iOS with only 1 development cycle. These apps are good on cutting costs, but usually fall short on performance.

Games, however, usually do not rely on HTML due to the high reaction time required of them, and their intensive graphic requirements.

Some developers develop games for Android using the basic Android APIs available, such as `Canvas`, or OpenGL-ES. Others chose to opt for game development tools such as Unity.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK is written in Java and contains the `View` class which allows you to actually render pixels on the screen. There are several approaches to rendering stuff in Android:

1. Create a custom `View` subclass and handle your rendering logic in Java or another JVM language (if your build setup allows for that)
2. Use a popular cross-platform engine and whatever API it provides, e.g. Unity
3. Make a web app - essentially a `WebView` packaged as an .apk pointing to an URL. With this approach, you do to use web technologies like HTML, CSS and JavaScript